# Is there a way of grouping Power BI pie chart slices?

Tags: pie-chart, powerbi

I have a large excel report with information on IT incidents and I need to create a pie chart in Power BI showing the number of incidents by priority (P1 to P5). But I need to group the priorities into two groups: P1 - P3 and P4 - P5.

I have the graph made already, but I can't find a way of grouping the slices.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use DAX to define an extra column as follows:

```
PriorityGroup = IF(OR(Incidents[Priority]="P4";Incidents[Priority]="P5");"P4-5";"P1-3")
```

And use this column in your pie chart.

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a Pie chart. In the 'Legend' field  Click the right-side down arrow. Then a dialog box is opened. In this box click New Group Option.

[image: Pie chart Slices group]

Then another dialog box Groups opened. Here you can create a group